# view.setText happening after loop?

Tags: java, android

i'm new to android programming. I have the following code happening on a button click

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.morse_btn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loopCode();
        }
    });
}
```

which calls this:

```
    public void loopCode()
{
        String code = "Hello There";
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_txt);
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
        {
           s+=code.charAt(i);
           view.setText(s);
           try {
               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

but when i run it on my phone, the text does not get appended until after the for loop has gone through, i.e i press the button, and after a few seconds, the whole string "Hello  There" appears.

How can I make it write the text one character at a time, like a typewriter style.

Thanks

Comment: you need to append the text not setext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `view.append("")` which will append new text to the existing one.

Try this code:

```
int i = 0; //declare this globally
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(i != 10) { 
                text.append(" " + i);
                i++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

This code will append a new number to the `TextView` every one second until it has reached the count 10. You can apply the same logic.

I had provided this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20293383/3025732) to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292760/display-values-dynamically-in-textview-android/20293383) -

**[EDIT]**

Try this:

```
String code = "Hello There"; //declare variable globally
int i = 0; //declare globally
TextView view; //declare globally

public void loopCode()
    {
                view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_txt);
                //String s = "";
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(i != code.length()) { 
                                view.append(" " + code.charAt(i));
                                i++;
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
     }
```

Don't forget to declare `int i = 0` and `String code = "Hello There"` globally.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Exist 2 different method setText in TextView.

- public final void setText (int resid)
- public final void setText (CharSequence text)

when you put variable int in setText, the android try find String in classe R variable in same code.
To resolve this you then cast int to string using String.valueOF(...)

see more in;
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)

try

```
       public void loopCode()
{
        String code = "Hello There";
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_txt);
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
        {

           view.setText(String.valueOf(i));
           try {
               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```